# Link with Screen Resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website that houses an animation and the resolution is 1024x768. The link for the website will be sent out as a Holiday greeting via email. Is there a way to prevent the website from loading in a different resolution than 1024x768 regardless of their screen resolution?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you frame and center your animation nicely instead. Using javascript popups is not gonna work and that would be the only way to define an exact browser window...

Comment: Does anyone else remember when people used to write JavaScript that would forcibly resize your browser to certain dimensions?  Boy am I glad I can tell my browser to not let that happen anymore.  Users generally have their browser/resolution the way they want it (or might not be able to change it at all) and get very unhappy when it gets changed/overwritten on them.

Comment: I understand this is bad practice, and personally I wouldn't even have asked how to do this, but this is what the client wants and they have given be a 2 week timeframe to do it. I let them know to come up with a backup option as well.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to only hide the content I would use media queries:
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

But if You have tracking pixels which You don't want to download I would insert an iframe if the screen resolution fits Your requirements:

```
if ( ($(window).height() === 768) && ($(window).width() === 1024) ) {
  $('body').append('<iframe src="http://your.url.com"></iframe>');
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't be much of a greeting... Lol

Answer (score 0):

just embed your content in a `div` setting the `width` and `height` to your desired values.

But a more robust solution would be to use media queries. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/